# Does nginx support SSL-SRP?

Tags: ssl, nginx, srp-protocol

Does nginx support the SRP (secure remote password) protocol?

I see that the ssl_ciphers directive accepts the format used by OpenSSL, but not clear if nginx actually supports all ciphers supported by OpenSSL.

I see no nginx documentation for SRP (for example, how to specify the verifier file), so does this mean SRP isn't supported by nginx?

Thanks,
Aliza

Comment: Seeing how Apache also doesn't have useful support for SRP (or anything else 'fancy', like client certificates), I came to the same conclusion two weeks ago: there is no support for SRP in nginx. Or Apache, for that matter (their solution is to make a verifier file, which doesn't scale at all).

Comment: It doesn't scale because you would have to duplicate the verifier file as many times as you have instances of Apache running?